# Do I need to pass the full path of a file in another directory to open()?

Tags: python, file-io, absolute-path

I have a folder with ten files in it which I want to loop through. When I print out the name of the file my code works fine:

```
import os
indir = '/home/des/test'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for f in filenames:
        print(f)
```

Which prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But if I try to open the file in the loop I get an IO error:

```
import os
indir = '/home/des/test'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for f in filenames:
        log = open(f, 'r')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/des/my_python_progs/loop_over_dir.py", line 6, in <module>
log = open(f, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1'
>>>
```

Do I need to pass the full path of the file even inside the loop to `open()` them?

Comment: Are you trying to traverse a directory tree, or are you just interested in the regular files in a specific directory/folder?

Comment: I know this question is four years old, but it still doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: Yes. Related: [Python open() gives IOError: Errno 2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928/python-open-gives-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you need the full path.

```
log = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r')
```

Is the quick fix.  As the comment pointed out, `os.walk` decends into subdirs so you do need to use the current directory root rather than `indir` as the base for the path join.

Comment: `os.walk` descends into subdirs, so you shouldn't use `indir` here.  Use `root`.

Answer (score 92):

If you are just looking for the files in a single directory (ie you are *not* trying to traverse a directory tree, which it doesn't look like), why not simply use [os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir):

```
import os  
for fn in os.listdir('.'):
     if os.path.isfile(fn):
        print (fn)
```

in place of [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.walk). You can specify a directory path as a parameter for [os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir). [os.path.isfile()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=isfile#os.path.isfile) will determine if the given filename is for a file.

Comment: the OP's loop doesn't only print the files in one directory.  It prints the files (recursively) in every directory undearneath the input directory as well.

Comment: @mgilson I must be missing that in looking at OP's code (OP only refers to filenames not directories) and part of the question read "folder with ten files in it which i want to loop through." .. did I skip some information?

Comment: If the OP has the directory structure :`.` contains `file1`,`directory1` and `directory1` contains `file2`.  the OP's code will print `file1`,`file2` whereas your solution would print `file1`, `directory1`.  (sorry, this is really hard to explain in comments).

Comment: @mgilson No I trust you, let me look it over and make corrections or delete the answer if it's not appropriate - thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @mgilson I adjusted my answer to only deal with regular files.

Comment: closer.  But your answer still doesn't recuse into sub-directories the way `os.walk` does.  But I suppose you covered that with "if you are just looking for files in a single directory"...

Comment: @mgilson I don't see OP doing this (traversing a directory tree), OP ignores 2 of the 3 return values from os.walk and only uses the filename. In any case, I asked OP for a clarification.

Comment: Reading the OP's question (not code) and your answer again, I think I agree that this is the way to do it.  (+1).

Comment: @mgilson I think the use of os.walk() is misleading/unnecessary for this purpose unless I misunderstood the question totally. I guess OP will know.

Comment: I now agree.  (I was mislead by it ;).  We're on the same page now.

Comment: What does `fn` represent? File name?

Comment: @EthanBierlein yes, that's right, `fn` is short for filename, each time it iterates through the list of filenames in the current directory, this variable will take on a different filename.

Comment: Dont forget adding the full path to fn if you are iterating over some else than '.'  ....

Comment: To be more general, change '.' to `path` (variable), and update the if line to `if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fn)):`.

Answer (score 8):

You have to specify the path that you are working on:

```
source = '/home/test/py_test/'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for f in filenames:
        print f
        fullpath = os.path.join(source, f)
        log = open(fullpath, 'r')
```

Answer (score 4):

The examples to os.walk in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) show how to do this:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for f in filenames:
        log = open(os.path.join(root, f),'r')
```

How did you expect the "open" function to know that the string "1" is supposed to mean "/home/des/test/1" (unless "/home/des/test" happens to be your current working directory)?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a snippet that will walk the file tree for you:

```
indir = '/home/des/test'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(indir):
    for f in filenames:
        print(f)
        log = open(indir + f, 'r')
```