# Python sees the file name but gives "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, file-io, ipython

I am trying to get a bunch of images from a directory and python gives me this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File1.jpg'`

But 'File1.jpg' is the first file in the directory. Here is the code including the error:

```
filenames = [os.path.join(dirname, fname) for fname in os.listdir(dirname)]

filenames = filenames[:100]
assert(len(filenames) == 100)

filenames = [fname_i for fname_i in os.listdir(dirname)
                if fname_i.endswith('.jpg')]

imgs = [plt.imread(fname)[..., :3] for fname in filenames]
```

fails with FileNotFoundError and the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-bf6a187847c5> in <module>()
----> 1 imgs = [plt.imread(fname)[..., :3] for fname in filenames]

<ipython-input-9-bf6a187847c5> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 imgs = [plt.imread(fname)[..., :3] for fname in filenames]

/Users/dampa/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in imread(*args, **kwargs)
   2295 @docstring.copy_dedent(_imread)
   2296 def imread(*args, **kwargs):
-> 2297     return _imread(*args, **kwargs)
   2298 
   2299 

/Users/dampa/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in imread(fname, format)
   1304 
   1305     if ext not in handlers:
-> 1306         im = pilread(fname)
   1307         if im is None:
   1308             raise ValueError('Only know how to handle extensions: %s; '

/Users/dampa/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in pilread(fname)
   1282         except ImportError:
   1283             return None
-> 1284         image = Image.open(fname)
   1285         return pil_to_array(image)
   1286 

/Users/dampa/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2278             filename = str(fp.resolve())
   2279     if filename:
-> 2280         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2281 
   2282     try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File1.jpg'
```

Comment: The file you are accessing is not in the directory running the script. Usage of absolute path for opening the files is better way to prevent such error and debug the file location

Comment: BTW avoid javascript snippets markups for python code. I edited them out.

Comment: This is not a **Minimal working example**; see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri thanks, it worked!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for the edit, I keep that in mind.

Comment: @Blacksilver I will go through it, sorry.

Comment: @dampa don't worry, happens to everyone sometimes -- we're too tired to care and just copy-paste in our code :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to pass the full path of a file in another directory to open()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801309/do-i-need-to-pass-the-full-path-of-a-file-in-another-directory-to-open)

Comment: @Blacksilver: I hacked the OP's iPython markdown down to plain Python code.

Answer (score 1):

the first time, you're doing it right, adding directory name:

```
In [5]: filenames = [os.path.join(dirname, fname)
   ...:    ...:               for fname in os.listdir(dirname)]
```

but in your filter you're omitting to add directory name again.

That would be only repeats of Moinuddin's comment if it wasn't for a better solution: simply use `glob` to filter AND get absolute path:

```
import glob
filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(dirname,'*.jpg'))
```