# Dynamically create dataframes in pandas by reading a list of csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder containing 3 csv files:

```
a.csv
b.csv
c.csv
```

To read all the csv's in this folder and create a dataframe, I'm currently doing this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('b.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('c.csv')
```

Is there any way to automate the naming of the dataframes (df1, df2 and df3) and reading of all the csv files in that folder. Say, I have 10 csv files, I don't want to manually write 10 read statements in pandas.

For example, I don't want to write this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
......
......
......

df10 = pd.read_csv('j.csv')
```

Thanks!

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377998/how-can-i-iterate-over-files-in-a-given-directory) question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11801338/2204131).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite easily if you're willing to access a list of dataframes rather than have df1...dfn explicitly declared:

```
root= "YOUR FOLDER"
csvs= []  #container for the various csvs contained in the directory
dfs = []  #container for temporary dataframes

# collect csv filenames and paths 
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    for file in filenames:
        csvs.append(dirpath + '\\' + file)

# store each dataframe in the list
for f in csvs:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(f))
```

Then access like `dfs[0] ... dfs[n]`

Comment: In the OP's code he knows that `df1` corresponds to the file named `'a.csv'`.  If that's important I suppose op could make `dfs` a dictionary and add them by doing `dfs[f] = read_csv(f)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of DataFrames:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

dfs = {os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]: pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob('*.csv')}
# df1 equivalent dfs['a'] 
dfs['a']
```

Answer (score 0):

People may downvote this solution since I am asking you to play with `global` variables. But, this solves your problem.

```
dir= 'myDir'
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(dir):
    for a, f in enumerate(filenames):
        fullpath = os.path.join(dir, f)
        globals()['df%s' % str(a+1)] = pd.read_csv(fullpath)
```